# IIS7 URL Rewrite to redirect based on path

Tags: url, redirect, iis-7, url-rewriting

Using IIS 7.5 and URL Rewrite 2.0, how would I redirect the following:

https://main.mysite.com/help/2012/v1.2.3

to

https://help.mysite.com/2012/v1.2.3

And the part of the path after help will not always be 2012, it could be any recent year.  Same with the v1.2.3; it's a version number so it will change.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty common scenerio - here is a great article with lots of pictures that will help guide you through the process of creating a map for rewriting in IIS 7.5.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module

Your other options are a HttpHandler (module) or using a UrlRewriting framework (like MVC).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I had seen that article and found it to be helpful.  Ruslan has written some good articles on this.  But I need to redirect based upon the first part of the path "/help/", while the rest of the path will be variable.  So I somehow need to load that into a variable.  I'm not that 'fluent' in regular expressions, but I'll have to get into it enough to figure this out.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: It looks like if I use this rule: main\.mysite\.com/help/(.*) I will get the remainder of the path in {R:1} so my redirect will look like https://help\.mysite\.com/{R:1}.  Does that seem valid?

Comment: That seems valid to me, but there must be a better way. In MVC you can add a route map table which lets you do things like main\mySite\{0}\help\{1} where you can find and replace the values in {0} which would be the year in your case. Maybe more information in your question would help provide a better answer (like code!)