# How to redirect domain to subfolder in SharePoint

Tags: redirect, sharepoint, subdomain, subdirectory

I have a problem, I need to redirect a domain to a subfolder in SharePoint like this:

Subdomain.domain.com to www.domain.com/subfolder

If it was a physical domain it will be easy but the folder doesn't really exist.

Can you help me with this?

Thanks.

Ps: sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, due to the fact, that you want to redirect to a Folder in Sharepoint -> thats not possible with out of the box features. Also IIS Url Rewrite will not help.

The only way you could do is to combine the IIS Url Rewrite Feature with a custom logic on a SharePoint Custom Application Page for example.

That mean, you would rewrite

www.mydomain.com/mysubfolder

to

http://sharepoint/sites/solution/myredirectpage.aspx?foder=foldername

Then the page would take the library and takes the folder by C# code and then the correct url for the folder. After that it will redirect you to the correct folder.

"IIS URL Rewrite". Please have a look at

[Simple IIS URL Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7855469/simple-iis-url-rewrite)

[IIS7 URL Rewrite to redirect based on path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734896/iis7-url-rewrite-to-redirect-based-on-path)

or many other answers on that topic at
https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stackoverflow%20iis%20url%20rewrite